# How do add search functionality to my bootstrap searchbar in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add a search functionality to a searchbox that I created using bootstrap. I read somewhere that `<?php get_search_form(); ?>`would help but I am not sure how to use it with my existing searchbox.

This is what my searchbox looks like right now. I want to make this functional

```
<!--searchbox-->
        <div class="input-group ">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for anything">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Go</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
       <div class="input-group ">
            <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s"><?php _x( 'Search for:', 'label' ); ?></label>
            <input class="form-control"  type="text" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search for anything" />
            <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Go" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

Then you should have (search.php) file to showing the results

Comment: thats the correct answer, the important magic happens at ´name="s"´.
alternative one also couldt use <?php get_search_form(); ?> instead and Filter the output in functions.php with https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_search_form/